# Pentaho - Reconnect option when connection is not stable

Tags: pentaho

I use Pentaho to migrate data from SQL server to MySQL. Unfortunately, the connection to MySQL is not stable and it sometimes failed in the middle.
Is there any option in Pentaho that allow Reconnect to MySQL when the package lost connection then the Pentaho package can continue running.
Thanks,

Comment: How long does the transformation run before it fails? Is it within seconds, or after several minutes (15-20 mins)?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the DB connection using the wizard rather than using the new button.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using a share connection, so I just select connection name in the "Connection"

Answer (score 0):

I applied a work around to by pass this case. That is auto retry logic which include a loop if ERROR and still have data then I go back some steps.